# How to add items to dictionary in a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Really basic question but how do you do this? Is there an equivalent to the append function for lists? Let's say I have an empty dictionary and I have to parse through an xml file and add all the tags

```
tag_dic = {}
for i in loop:
  tag_dic[i]
return tag_dic
```

I tried this and it gives me an error so maybe there is another way?

Comment: the answer to your question is in the docstring for dict.  at the minimum, you should look at a function's docstring before coming to stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary is a mapping from a key to a value. You need to provide a value, at the very least something that signifies 'no value':

```
tag_dic[i] = None
```

Comment: Thanks this worked once I added a value. The whole problem actually dealt with counting the tags as the 'value' so I incremented starting at 1 and it worked.